# Form input gets unfocused after typing in 1 character

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx

I'm using react-MDBootstrap on Reactjs. So I had this problem input unfocused every one character typed. Here's my code :

```
onChange = ({ target }) =>
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    })
    .
    .
    .

<MDBInput
      icon="envelope"
      type="text"
      name="nim"
      label="Masukkan username"
      onChange={this.onChange}
      validate
      error="salah"
      success="benar"
      value={this.state.nim}
/>
```

what is wrong with this behavior? I've checked the state it's changed fine.

**UPDATED**

This is the return from my class Login form :

```
return (
      <Section>
        <MDBContainer>
          <div className="box mx-auto mt-5">
            <br />

            <MDBRow>
              <Logo src={logoIcon} alt="logo.png" className="mx-auto" />
            </MDBRow>
            <MDBRow>
              <Card className="mx-auto mt-4 mb-2">
                <div className="card-block">
                  {/* Header */}
                  <div className="text-center purple pt-2 text-white">
                    <div className="my-1">
                      <span className="h4">Login</span>
                    </div>
                    <hr className="mt-2 mb-2" />
                  </div>

                  {/* <!--Body--> */}
                  <div className="md-form mx-4">
                    <MDBInput
                      icon="envelope"
                      type="text"
                      name="nim"
                      label="Masukkan username"
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      validate
                      error="salah"
                      success="benar"
                      value={this.state.nim}
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="md-form mx-4">
                    <i className="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                    <input
                      name="password"
                      type="password"
                      id="form4"
                      onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                      value={this.state.password}
                      className="form-control"
                    />
                    <label for="form4">Masukkan password</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="text-center">
                    <button className="btn btn-deep-purple w-75">Login</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/* <!--Footer--> */}
                <MDBModalFooter className="mx-auto">
                  <div class="options">
                    <p>
                      Belum daftar?
                      <Link to="/register">Daftar di sini</Link>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </MDBModalFooter>
              </Card>
            </MDBRow>
            {/* <!--/Form without header--> */}
            <MDBRow>
              <small class="register mx-auto text-white">
                Copyright &copy; 2019 Fakultas Kedokteran Hewan Universitas
                Brawijaya. All Rights Reserved.
              </small>
            </MDBRow>
          </div>
        </MDBContainer>
      </Section>
    )
```

Inside the render just styled-components variable and onChange() function.

Comment: are you passing any key?

Comment: nope, just like that.

Comment: can you try to pass a unique key, which won't be changing

Comment: I've added the key, but it still auto unfocused.

Comment: Something is causing your component to rerender on each change. You'll need to provide more context to the code in order for me to able to tell what exactly (in some cases - it might be a container component that's rerendered). As mentioned above - adding a key may help in some cases by letting react know this is the same component.

Comment: as Moshe mentioned the component is mounting and remounting, so each time constructs that can be the issue, try finding in that way or provide some more code it will be helpful for us to figure it